# How can I find the first time of each day in a list of dicts containing timestamps?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, datetime

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
data = [
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 27, 8, 0), "km": 10},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 27, 13, 30), "km": 20},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 27, 17, 30), "km": 40},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 28, 9, 15), "km": 15},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 28, 14, 45), "km": 25}
]
```

Now I want to find the first time of each day and assign km = 0. Which should lead to this:

```
data = [
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 27, 8, 0), "km": 0},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 27, 13, 30), "km": 20},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 27, 17, 30), "km": 40},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 28, 9, 15), "km": 0},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 28, 14, 45), "km": 25}
]
```

How can I do this?

So far I did not even find a good starting point to approach this issue.

Comment: Use the `min()` function with a key that extracts the `Zeit` element to get the dictionary with the minimum time.

Comment: Why were 15 km changed to 0 km?

Comment: The problem is that I am not looking for the absolute minimum of all elements, but the minimum of each sub-group, which are the different days. It should make km = 0, if it occurs the first time of a day.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but: why is this Python data instead of an(y kind of) database that you can query to do exactly these kinds of things?

Comment: In that case it may be easier if you convert to a pandas dataframe. Then you can use `.groupby()` to process it by day.

Comment: It actually comes from a SQL query. Any hint what to do in SQL achieve this?

Comment: @Barmar eh, this is trivial with pure python, no need to involved pandas.

Comment: @DrZoidberg09 That would have been useful to [mention in your post](/help/how-to-ask), because that basically makes this a SQL question, not a Python question. The exact query will depend on your table schema, so time to [edit] your post =)

Comment: Yeah, if you can do this in SQL, you probably should do that, although, it is perfectly easy in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 27, 8, 0), "km": 10},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 27, 13, 30), "km": 20},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 27, 17, 30), "km": 40},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 28, 9, 15), "km": 15},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 28, 14, 45), "km": 25},
]

# sort if needed:
# data.sort(key=lambda d: d["Zeit"])

for _, g in groupby(data, lambda d: (d["Zeit"].year, d["Zeit"].month, d["Zeit"].day)):
    first = next(g)
    first["km"] = 0

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {"Zeit": datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 27, 8, 0), "km": 0},
    {"Zeit": datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 27, 13, 30), "km": 20},
    {"Zeit": datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 27, 17, 30), "km": 40},
    {"Zeit": datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 28, 9, 15), "km": 0},
    {"Zeit": datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 28, 14, 45), "km": 25},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like the list will always be sorted. One way would be to loop through the list and once the day changes then assign km = 0.

The solution that worked for me was:

```
from datetime import datetime
data = [
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 27, 8, 0), "km": 10},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 27, 13, 30), "km": 20},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 27, 17, 30), "km": 40},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 28, 9, 15), "km": 15},
    {"Zeit": datetime(2024, 2, 28, 14, 45), "km": 25}
]

current = -1
for entry in data:
    if current != (current := entry["Zeit"].date()):
        entry["km"] = 0
        current = entry["Zeit"].date()
```

EDIT: used @juanpa.arrivillaga's suggestion

Comment: it might work, but strictly speaking, you cannot rely on just `.day`, that assumes that there are no dates like `datetime(2024, 2, 27)` and `datetime(2024, 3, 27)` next to each other

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So, `.date()`? And to avoid double work: `if current != (current := entry["Zeit"].date()):` :-)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's a good point I forgot about that case thank you.

Comment: @HarryFoster1812 Note that with my tricky expression, you don't need your last line anymore.

Answer (score -2):

Convert your DateTime to a Unix timestamp and then sort them in ascending way. The first one in the list will be the one which you are looking for.

Start with below piece of code:

```
import datetime
import time
 
date_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 26, 21, 20)

unix_timestamp = time.mktime(date_time.timetuple())
```

Comment: Why would you need to convert to unix timestamps to sort them? Do you think sorting doesn't work on datetime values?

Comment: But what does this have to do with finding the first time in each date? You misread it the same way as I initially did, didn't you see the OP's correction comment?

Comment: this doesn't really address the question, and there is no need to convert to a `str` object to sort the data

Comment: There's also no need to sort to get the minimum. Python has a built-in `min()` function.